# Need to find key-value pair and replace key-value pair in JSON using JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have this JSON

```json
{
  "firstName": "Rajesh",
  "lastName": "Kumar",
  "gender": "man",
  "age": 24,
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "126 Udhna",
    "city": "Surat",
    "state": "WB",
    "postalCode": "394221"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "7383627627"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to find the value of the "state" key Using JQ and replace the value in JSON. I do not want to fetch it by providing the position of the key, Like

```sh
firstName=$(cat sample-json.json | jq -r '.firstName')
```

My expected output

```json
{
  "firstName": "Rajesh",
  "lastName": "Kumar",
  "gender": "man",
  "age": 24,
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "126 Udhna",
    "city": "Surat",
    "state": "Bihar",
    "postalCode": "394221"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "7383627627"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How do you want to fetch it then?

Comment: So you want to change the value of the `state` key?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to specify .address:

```
jq '.address.state = "Bihar"' sample-json.json
```

Otherwise:

```
jq 'walk(if type == "object" and has("state") then .state = "Bihar" else . end)' sample-json.json
```

This last will replace all `.state` values.  If you only want to replace the first occurrence:

```
jq 'first(..|objects|select(has("state"))).state = "Bihar"' sample-json.json
```

And so on.  It would really help all concerned if you could make the requirements clear.

Comment: Getting below error - jq: error: walk/1 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
walk(if type == "object" and has("state") then .state = "Bihar" else . end)
jq: 1 compile error

Comment: Your version of jq must be very old. If you have no better options, you can simply copy its def, available online. E.g. google for: def walk jq builtin

Comment: Used this to install JQ -
#!/bin/bash
export PATH="$PATH:."
curl -s -L https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.5/jq-linux64 > ./jq
chmod +x ./jq

Comment: Why would you want to install a very old version?